# UK visitor visa for wife

Tags: visas, uk, applications, family

I am planning a trip to the UK with my wife and wanted some guidance on the same. We hold Indian passports and are currently residing in Singapore.

I have an EP (Employment Pass) and my wife is on a dependent pass. Currently my wife has no source of income and hence she does not have a bank account in Singapore, my bank account does not have her name as the joint applicant.

My questions are

1. How do I mention in the form that I will be paying for her travel too?
2. Also is it ok to submit my bank statements having my name for her application?
3. For my application, I am giving an HR letter stating my position current salary and period of leave, anything similar to be submitted for her case?

Comment: What is an EP in this context?

Comment: Employment pass